# Retrieve derived entities with DbSet.SqlQuery

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to use DbSet.SqlQuery(string, object[]) to return entities derived from the entity in the DbSet.

This should be possible according to the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx):

> Creates a raw SQL query that will return entities in this set. By default, the entities returned are tracked by the context; this can be changed by calling AsNoTracking on the DbRawSqlQuery returned. Note that the entities returned are always of the type for this set and never of a derived type. If the table or tables queried may contain data for other entity types, then the SQL query must be written appropriately to ensure that only entities of the correct type are returned

Is this possible? I havent found a way to do this.

I've tried to use Database.SqlQuery but the entities returned is not tracked and doesnt have its navigation properties set (which I need).

My code looks something like this:

```
public class Notification
{
...
}

public class PageNotification : Notification
{
...
}

public class SystemNotification : Notification
{
...
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to solve this. All I had to do was to add an extra DbSet for the derived type and run the SqlQuery on that set, like this:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext 
{
    DbSet<Notifikation> Notifications { get; set; }
    DbSet<PageNotifikation> PageNotifications { get; set; }
}

MyContext.PageNotifications.SqlQuery(...)
```